# getting error FATAL: /home/labuser/b.o has no symtab? make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1 on compiling a linux driver file

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I have written wrapper functions for LED management in C. Basically i am using device drivers in Linux programming. But on compiling i am getting the following Error.

make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic/ M=`pwd` modules

```
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
FATAL: /home/labuser/b.o has no symtab?
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic'
```

I am using kernel space header files. and compiling the file using makefile. What can be the probable cause of this Error??